# Google map: adding different image marker depending on array value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing the following to add markers to a google map from an array.

My question refers to the end of the function where im trying to set `marker.icon = imageUnlikely;` I'm trying to get the marker to be an image not the standard Google maps marker, but it doesn't work. If I add `icon: imageUnlikely` to the `marker` object the image displays correctly.

Any ideas?

```
var imageUnlikely = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/BeachApp/maps/Unlikely.PNG', new google.maps.Size(15, 14));

function SetupMarkers(map, locations) {
var shapeNoUpdate = {
coord: [0, 0, 218, 200],
type: 'rect'
};

var shapeWithUpdate = {
coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 55, 20, 55, 1],
type: 'poly'
};

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var beach = locations[i];

    var beachId = beach[7];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,   
        shape: shapeNoUpdate,
        title: beach[0] + ' - pollution ' + beach[4],
        beachId: beachId,        
        arrayIndex: i

    });

    if (beach[4] == 'Unlikely') {
        marker.icon = imageUnlikely;
    } 

}
}

SetupMarkers(map4, beaches4);
```

Comment: While geocodezip has pointed out where you are doing wrong, I dont see where you are trying to fetch a new icon for a marker in each for loop iteration. Tell me if I missed it.

Comment: I've removed the other part of the if statement for brevity. There are different types of markers depending on the value of beach[4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use undocumented properties (the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) doesn't have any documented properties).  Use the documented methods, in this case setIcon().

Example (not tested):

```
 if (beach[4] == 'Unlikely') {
    marker.setIcon(imageUnlikely);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't understand though. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks, I did a bit of reading and tried that too. It works. Thanks for the help.